# facebook fql result to json_encode array

Tags: php, arrays, facebook-fql, json

newbie here, my code below outputs like this `[{"src":"http","src":"http"},{"src":"http","src":"http"}]` using json_encode. however my requirement would be like this `[["http","http"],["http","http"]]`

```
//to get album cover
        $fql2    =   "select  src from photo where pid = '" . $values['cover_pid'] . "'";
        $param2  =   array(
         'method'    => 'fql.query',
         'query'     => $fql2,
         'callback'  => ''
        );

        $fqlResult2   =   $facebook->api($param2);
        $jsarr  =   array();
        foreach( $fqlResult2 as $keys2 => $values2){
        }
        if ($values['name'] != 'Profile Pictures'){
            $jsarr['src'] = $album['src'];

                $count += 1;

        if ($count == 1){
        echo "[";}
        else {
        echo ",";}
        echo json_encode($values2);
        }
    }
    echo "]";
}
?>
```

my json_encode output is like this

```
[{"src":"http:\/\/photos-c.ak.fbcdn.net\/hphotos-ak-snc6\/251383_221168744573533_221167777906963_849177_3220954_s.jpg"},{"src":"http:\/\/photos-d.ak.fbcdn.net\/hphotos-ak-ash4\/248958_221168431240231_221167777906963_849167_3802855_s.jpg"}]
```

how do i output it this way

```
[["http:\/\/photos-c.ak.fbcdn.net\/hphotos-ak-snc6\/251383_221168744573533_221167777906963_849177_3220954_s.jpg"],["http:\/\/photos-d.ak.fbcdn.net\/hphotos-ak-ash4\/248958_221168431240231_221167777906963_849167_3802855_s.jpg"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple way would be to save the `json_encode` result to a variable, and then [str_replace](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp) the `{` and `}` characters.

So your code would become:

```
//to get album cover
    $fql2    =   "select  src from photo where pid = '" . $values['cover_pid'] . "'";
    $param2  =   array(
     'method'    => 'fql.query',
     'query'     => $fql2,
     'callback'  => ''
    );

    $fqlResult2   =   $facebook->api($param2);
    $jsarr  =   array();
    foreach( $fqlResult2 as $keys2 => $values2){
    }
    if ($values['name'] != 'Profile Pictures'){
        $jsarr['src'] = $album['src'];

            $count += 1;

    if ($count == 1){
    $outputStr .= "[";}
    else {
    $outputStr .= ",";}
    $outputStr .= json_encode($values2);
    }
}
$outputStr .= "]";
$outputStr = str_replace("{","[",$outputStr);
$outputStr = str_replace("}","]",$outputStr);
echo $outputStr;
}
?>
```

Comment: Note that you would want to instantiate `$outputStr` with `$outputStr = "";` somewhere before the first use (as part of clean coding). I didn't do that above, since I wasn't entirely sure what code comes before this (since there's a chance you'd want to use the `$outputStr` in some of that too).